# Client oplock error, saving records in CloudKit

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I have an oplock error that occurs from time saving to CloudKit. I can't seem to be able to find out why, but I suspect it happens when I manually edit CKRecords from the CloudKit dashboard and then fetch and modify that record from the app. Does anyone have an explanation to what oplock means and where I should start looking?

This is the error

```
Error Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x79c42d60; 418deec9-ee5e-46b8-8877-606c14a5fe92:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> to server: client oplock error updating record
```

This is my code, note that the error appears even if I don't change the record

```
    [self.publicDB saveRecord:self.currentUser completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error)
 {


     if(error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }

     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Saved access to Cloudkit");

     }

 }];
```

Comment: Could you show us your code where it goes wrong plus the exact output of the error that you get?

Comment: Ok, thanks  - updated with code and error

Comment: an oplock error usually means that you do not have the right to update the data. Are you sure that your record is from the same publicDB? Is the record created by someone else and do you have the security set that you can only update your own data?

Comment: Yes its  the default container, public db and most of the time the code works, I just occasionally get this error (and my suspicion is that the record is locked, maybe for a while, when you edit it in the dashboard).

Comment: Do you get a ChangeTokenExpired error? You can get the error code using:         let errorCode:CKErrorCode = CKErrorCode(rawValue: error!.code)!
  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CKErrorCode

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are getting this error because the version of the User record on the server is newer than what you're trying to update it with.  If you take the error code *rawValue* (**14**) and map it to the *CKErrorCode* enum, you see it maps to:

```
CKErrorCode.ServerRecordChanged /* The record was rejected because the version
                                   on the server was different */
```

This is why @shawnynicole answer above solves the issue with a `fetchRecordWithId` right before the attempt to save the user record.

I've found if very helpful to parse all the CloudKit error codes and add to the message description as per Apple's comments...otherwise you get error messages like: *"client oplock error updating record"* !!

The CKError code & comments can be found in the CloudKit headers:

```
public enum CKErrorCode : Int { 
  case InternalError /* CloudKit.framework encountered an error.  This is a non-recoverable error. */
  case PartialFailure /* Some items failed, but the operation succeeded overall */
  case NetworkUnavailable /* Network not available */
  case NetworkFailure /* Network error (available but CFNetwork gave us an error) */
  case BadContainer /* Un-provisioned or unauthorized container. Try provisioning the container before retrying the operation. */
  case ServiceUnavailable /* Service unavailable */
  case RequestRateLimited /* Client is being rate limited */
  case MissingEntitlement /* Missing entitlement */
  case NotAuthenticated /* Not authenticated (writing without being logged in, no user record) */
  case PermissionFailure /* Access failure (save or fetch) */
  case UnknownItem /* Record does not exist */
  case InvalidArguments /* Bad client request (bad record graph, malformed predicate) */
  case ResultsTruncated /* Query results were truncated by the server */
  case ServerRecordChanged /* The record was rejected because the version on the server was different */
  case ServerRejectedRequest /* The server rejected this request.  This is a non-recoverable error */
  case AssetFileNotFound /* Asset file was not found */
  case AssetFileModified /* Asset file content was modified while being saved */
  case IncompatibleVersion /* App version is less than the minimum allowed version */
  case ConstraintViolation /* The server rejected the request because there was a conflict with a unique field. */
  case OperationCancelled /* A CKOperation was explicitly cancelled */
  case ChangeTokenExpired /* The previousServerChangeToken value is too old and the client must re-sync from scratch */
  case BatchRequestFailed /* One of the items in this batch operation failed in a zone with atomic updates, so the entire batch was rejected. */
  case ZoneBusy /* The server is too busy to handle this zone operation. Try the operation again in a few seconds. */
  case BadDatabase /* Operation could not be completed on the given database. Likely caused by attempting to modify zones in the public database. */
  case QuotaExceeded /* Saving a record would exceed quota */
  case ZoneNotFound /* The specified zone does not exist on the server */
  case LimitExceeded /* The request to the server was too large. Retry this request as a smaller batch. */
  case UserDeletedZone /* The user deleted this zone through the settings UI. Your client should either remove its local data or prompt the user before attempting to re-upload any data to this zone. */
}
```

Comment: Could you help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50044092/cloudkit-error-handling-with-ckfetchrecordzonechangesoperation because I don't receive any error. Just cloudkit keeps fetching the record.

Answer (score 5):

I was having this error too.

I resolved it by making sure that I always call `fetchRecordWithID` first, then call `saveRecord` inside the `fetchRecordWithID` completion handler.

Take note that `fetchRecordWithID` will return `CKErrorCodeUnknownItem` for new records. Be sure to handle the error appropriately. I bypass the error so that my code will continue on to `saveRecord`, which will insert the record into CloudKit, (given there are no errors with `saveRecord` of course).